# Silverlight listbox orderby

Tags: c#, silverlight, list, listbox

Is there a way to order this silverlight bound ListBox. I am not sure the way I have populated makes it easy?

Code sample here:

```
  XElement _xml = XElement.Load("MSA.xml");
        {
            msa.Items.Clear();

            foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("channel").Elements("msa"))
            {
                MSAFeedItem _item = new MSAFeedItem();
                _item.Lat = double.Parse(value.Element("lat").Value);
                _item.Long = double.Parse(value.Element("long").Value);
                _item.Name = value.Element("n").Value;


 double dis1 = _item.Lat - curLatitude;
                        double dis2 = _item.Long - curLongitude;

                     var miles1 = Math.Pow(dis1, 2.0);
                     var miles2 = Math.Pow(dis2, 2.0);

                     var miles3 = miles1 + miles2;

                     var miles4 = Math.Sqrt(miles3) ;

                     var miles = miles4 * 62.1371192;

                    _item.Distance = Decimal.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(miles));

                 msa.Items.Add(_item);

            }
        }
```

It needs to be in ascending order according to a double or decimal value called 'miles'
ListBox is called 'msa'

Many thanks for any help or suggestions.

EDIT: Ive added my distance code to help you understand whats going on, so _item.distance or 'miles' is the number it needs to ascend by.
The code is a bit messy and doesnt work exactly rightt but you get the idea.

Comment: so `miles` is independent of the data from XML from you want to sort by that?

Comment: Hi Yes, 'miles' is genereated from a bit of code that is missing in the above example. (basically working out how many miles you are from a particular location)

Comment: Edited my question/code to help understand what im doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 XElement _xml = XElement.Load("MSA.xml");
        {
            msa.Items.Clear();
            List<MSAFeedItem> tempItems = new List<MSAFeedItem>();

            foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("channel").Elements("msa"))
            {
                MSAFeedItem _item = new MSAFeedItem();
                _item.Lat = double.Parse(value.Element("lat").Value);
                _item.Long = double.Parse(value.Element("long").Value);
                _item.Name = value.Element("n").Value;


                double dis1 = _item.Lat - curLatitude;
                double dis2 = _item.Long - curLongitude;

                     var miles1 = Math.Pow(dis1, 2.0);
                     var miles2 = Math.Pow(dis2, 2.0);

                     var miles3 = miles1 + miles2;

                     var miles4 = Math.Sqrt(miles3) ;

                     var miles = miles4 * 62.1371192;

                    _item.Distance = Decimal.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(miles));

                 tempItems.Add(_item);

            }

           tempItems.OrderBy( i => i.Distance).ToList()
                    .ForEach(e => msa.Items.Add(e));

        }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, this looks good, but what is .AddRange after Items.? There is no extension for that of Items.

Comment: Hi Thanks SOE, AddRange isnt coming up. Its because 'msa' which is my ListBox is from System.Windows.controls. hence the error message im getting: Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\msa_uk\msa_uk\Nearest.xaml.cs 118 27 msa_uk. This is a silverlight based Windows Phone 7 project if that make a diff.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to go here is to use a list, which binds to the listbox:

```
        var elements = new List<MSAFeedItem>();
        var comparison = new Comparison<MSAFeedItem>(
            (x, y) => {
                if (x.Miles < y.Miles) return -1;
                else if (x.Miles > y.Miles) return 1;
                else return 0;
            });
        foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("channel").Elements("msa")) 
        { 
            MSAFeedItem _item = new MSAFeedItem(); 
            _item.Lat = double.Parse(value.Element("lat").Value);
            _item.Long = double.Parse(value.Element("long").Value); 
            _item.Name = value.Element("n").Value; 
            _item.Distance = Decimal.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(miles)); 
            elements.Add(_item); 
        }

        elements.Sort(comparison);

        msa.ItemsSource = elements;
```

Obviously replacing the Miles property on the X and Y items with the way you calculate the amount of miles.

Comment: Thanks, Edited my question/code to help you understand what im doing. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Adding to a list is the right way to go. You can use Linq to sort on the property - `elements.OrderBy(i => i.Distance)`